# Calculate means of fields with same name in cell of structures

Tags: matlab, structure, operation

I have a cell containing a number of structures, containing the output from the MirToolBox mirfeatures() function for a number of audio signals. The field names are the same for each structure.

So the data looks something like this, but much larger. c{1} is the first structure, c{2} is the second structure etc. Both structures contain the same field names.

```
c{1}.field1.field1A=1;
c{1}.field1.field1B=2;
c{1}.field1.field1C=3;
c{1}.field2.field2D.field2E=4;
c{1}.field2.field2D.field2F=5;
c{1}.field3=6;
c{1}.field4.field4A.field4B.field4C=7;
c{1}.field4.field4A.field4B.field4D=8;
c{2}.field1.field1A=9;
c{2}.field1.field1B=10;
c{2}.field1.field1C=11;
c{2}.field2.field2D.field2E=12;
c{2}.field2.field2D.field2F=13;
c{2}.field3=14;
c{2}.field4.field4A.field4B.field4C=15;
c{2}.field4.field4A.field4B.field4D=16;
```

I'd like to calculate the mean values of each field, across structures e.g.

The mean of `c{1}.field1.field1A, c{2}.field1.field1A,..  c{n}.field1.field1A=9`.

Is there a straightforward way of doing this, bearing in mind the actual structures that I'm working with have approaching a hundred fields each?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cell2mat` to convert your cell array to a struct array, and then access a field over the *whole* array (as opposed to simply from a single struct element from that array) to get a comma-separated list. If the field points to another struct, your comma separated list will be a comma separated list of structs!

Then you can collect that comma-separated list into a cell array again, by surrounding it with `{}`, and performing a `cell2mat` again, and so forth for each level in your struct, to obtain struct arrays of the same size as your initial cell array, containing only the fields you need.

When you've finally travelled enough levels down to reach the field of interest, you can collect it again as a comma separated list, and wrap it around `[]` to make it into a matrix, which you can use as an argument to your function (e.g. mean).

Unfortunately, you'll have to do this for each unique innermost field you have, because there is no consistency between them. But it does allow you to process all N cells in a single operation for each unique field.

e.g. given your above cell of size 2, and if we denote s0, s1, s2 as outermost, one level deep, two levels deep, etc, then:

```
% Convert outer cell array to struct array representing outermost level
s0 = cell2mat(c); % -> 1x2 struct array containing the fields: field1, field2, field3, field4

% field 1 - subfields of interest are 1 level deep
s1 = cell2mat({s0.field1}); % -> 1x2 struct array containing the fields: field1A, field1B, field1C
field1A_mean = mean([s1.field1A])
field1B_mean = mean([s1.field1B])
field1C_mean = mean([s1.field1C])

% field 2 - subfields of interest are 2 levels deep
s1 = cell2mat({s0.field2}); % -> 1x2 struct array containing the field: field2D
s2 = cell2mat({s1.field2D}); % -> 1x2 struct array containing the fields: field2E, field2F 
field2E_mean = mean([s2.field2E])
field2F_mean = mean([s2.field2F])

% field 3 - collect at this level
field3_mean = mean([s0.field3])

% field 4 subfields of interest are 3 levels deep
s1 = cell2mat({s0.field4});
s2 = cell2mat({s1.field4A});
s3 = cell2mat({s2.field4B});
field4C_mean = mean([s3.field4C])
field4D_mean = mean([s3.field4D])
```

Comment: Having said that, it's generally a bad idea to have variables called "var1 var2 var3" when you could have an array instead, especially if you intend to iterate over the variables later on. Furthermore, there's no reason to have sub-struct-levels just to group the inner fields, as this complicates your design. If the design of the construct is not out of your control, then I'd consider redesigning the struct itself to make such calculations more straightforward. (i.e. a single outermost struct array, where each struct only contains the 'leaf' fields of interest).

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. By "it's generally a bad idea to have variables called "var1 var2 var3" when you could have an array instead, especially if you intend to iterate over the variables later on", are you referring to s1, s2 etc, or the field names? If the latter, these were just dummy names for use in the example above.

Comment: No, the latter (The former is just a necessary evil of having to collect temp variables). I'm saying, your datastructure is unnecessarily complex. Use something more straightforward to make your life easier. *Either* have a struct where all fields are *data* (i.e. make fields `1A`, `1B`, `1C`, `2E`, `2F`, `3`, `4C` and `4D` direct fields of the parent struct, and discard the rest), *Or* forget about structs altogether, and create a 2D cell array, where rows are items, and columns are fields. Then all you have to do is `mean([c{:,1}])` for the 1st mean "field", `mean([c{:,2}])` for the 2nd etc.

Comment: Unless, of course, you're not the one generating this data and it's just something you are given in that form. But even then, it might be worth pre-processing it into something more manageable, rather than having to fight against the awkward structure every time you want to access something.

Comment: Also, if you have access to the *Statistics Toolbox* your particular use-case sounds like it might benefit from matlab's `dataset` class instead of simple structs or cells. Have a look at `help dataset` to see what it is, and `help dataset/dataset` to see how you can create one. (and `help dataset/[TAB][TAB]` to see what overloaded functions exist specifically for the dataset type)